# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI when the project is launched

Tags: java, spring

Please check and a hint where I made a mistake when configuring the beginning of the project because I get the error " No mapping found for HTTP request with URI " . The following codes are added to the project.
1.web.xml
2.servlet - context.xml
3. @ Controller

In addition, a link is added to the screen of my tree design.
http://zapodaj.net/17ab5a68373a9.png.html

1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">



    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.konrad.hh" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />





    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.konrad.hh" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"

        p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bazahealthhelper"
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:username="konrad"
        p:password="konrad">
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManager"></beans:bean>




    <beans:bean id="entityManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"></beans:bean>
```

3.

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl; 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("allUsers", userServiceImpl.allUsers() );

        return "home";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1). Addin seervlet-context.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
```

2). change your servlet mapping in web.xml as below:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: This is my project if you have some time look this : http://www.megafileupload.com/118S/project.zip

Comment: I have this warning: WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hh/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Comment: replace "hh" with "home"